# TypeScript Filtrar array de objetos evaluando todos sus atributos

Tags: typescript, es6

tengo el siguiente problema, necesito filtrar los objetos de un array usando un valor buscado (generalmente un string) pero que verifique todos los atributo del objeto (es diccionario clave/valor, no es otra cosa) y no solo uno especifico, hasta el momento hacia:

```
let busqueda = 'algo'
lista.filter(e => e.nombre.indexOf(busqueda) != -1)
```

Pero esto solo me sirve para filtrar por un solo atributo, quiero que el filtro se aplique para todos los atributos, extra no siempre son los mismos los atributos del objeto, asi que minimo necesitaria alguna forma de acceder a ellos ya que no siempre los conosco o varian.

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A falta de respuestas al problema me auto respondo, la solución que encontré al problema es la siguiente:

Javascript provee una forma de obtener todas las claves de un objeto

```
Array.keys(object)
```

suponiendo que todos los elementos de la lista son idénticos, solo hace falta
obtener la lista de claves del primero y luego ir recorriendo elemento por elemento, los resultados se podrían concatenar pero podría darse el caso de obtener elementos duplicados por lo que el array resultante de cada iteración de filtro debe ser recorrido nuevamente para unicamente extraer los elementos no duplicados, la solucion quedaria asi,

no se si sera la mejor alternativa pero funciona:

```
function buscarEnArrayDic(lista, busqueda) { 
    let keys = Array.keys(lista[0]);
    let result = [];
    for (let k of keys) {
        let subresult = lista.filter(e => e[k].indexOf(busqueda) != -1);
        for (let e of subresult) {
            if (result.indexOf(e) == -1) {
                result.push(e);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Saludos